# Reuse a single GLSurfaceView nested inside multiple activities

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, kotlin, glsurfaceview

I have a usecase to make a single GLSurfaceView context, then reuse it on different Activity pages in an Android application as of API 26. In other words, I have a single OpenGL scene with GL state saved inside the context, that must be useable from different 'pages' in the Android app. Creating new GLSurfaceViews is out of the question, because we cannot lose the state we've put into GL when we change pages.

Surely I'm not the only person who has need of this... how is it done? All examples assume you don't need to show the same scene on multiple activities, or that it's perfectly acceptable to waste a bunch of time/memory recreating the same GL state over and over.

I'm aware of the 'activity life cycle', which is why I've tried to entertain the notion of making a 'dedicated' GlSurfaceView activity, and then attempting to figure out how to 'nest' this dedicated activity in other activities, but I'm unsure if that method could achieve the correct end. Thoughts?

EDIT - I forgot to mention -- is this possible with 'fragments'?
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments

Comment: One could argue: Why would you need to switch to a different activity if the state is the same?

Comment: I have a GL view that i need to integrate into existing code which has a lot of work done separated into multiple activities. I'm not at liberty to rewrite the whole app to use a single activity, unfortunately...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update -- As near as I can tell this is intentionally walled off by Android API. Their intention with GLSurfaceView appears to be that it is tied to one activity only, EVER. When that Activity is gone, your GL context is 100 percent always gone.

This is why most applications with GL needs do not ever move between activities, and resort to operating within a single Activity